# Why does the Tika facade choose EmptyParser?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm using the Tika facade, per the example of the [elasticsearch-mappper-attachment plugin](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/blob/208c76e45e5104f9d03825a23a68b5e4af5694bc/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/attachment/AttachmentMapper.java#L461). Here's my test code:

```
Tika tika = new Tika();                                                                                                                                                                                 
Metadata md = new Metadata();

try {                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    String content = tika.parseToString(src, md, 100000);

    System.out.println("Content length: " + content.length());  

    for (String s: md.names()) {                                                                                                                                                                        
        System.out.println(s + ": " + md.get(s));                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                       
catch (TikaException e) {                                                                                                                                                                               
    System.out.println(e);                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Content length: 0
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser
Content-Type: text/html
```

So the question is: if Tika correctly identifies the input as `text/html`, why does it use the `EmptyParser`? If I'm supposed to pass a parser, which parser should I pass for best results, assuming that autodetection is successful, as above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that `tika-parsers` is on your classpath! If you are using Gradle,

```
compile 'org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.7'
```

will do the trick.