# Jackrabbit Oak Binary property in Solr index has not correct value

Tags: solr, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I use remote solr index. I have one node type that has a binary property. When I add a node with this type and attach some non empty text file, oak add a document in solr but the value of binary field is some new line character.
I trace it and find that the binary value that extract in `SolrIndexEditor` class line 235 return a LinkedList with one entry that just contain "\n\n\n\n\n". Is there any config that I missed or there is a bug here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the tika parser in my dependencies. So by adding it the problem solved. I fine the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954805/why-does-the-tika-facade-choose-emptyparser)